# How to calculate the difference of dates?

Tags: java, datetime, date-difference

Im using `java.util.Date` class and want to compare a `Date` object and the current time.

output format must be like this :

```
... years , ... months , ... days , ...hours , ... minutes , ... seconds.
```

this is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2022, 1 , 25 , 12 , 20 , 33);
    Date now = new Date(); //Tue Feb 25 11:49:05 IRST 2020
    Date date = calendar.getTime(); //Fri Feb 25 12:20:33 IRST 2022
}
```

is there a simple way to calculate that?

Comment: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-calculate-date-time-difference-in-java/

Comment: How long is a year? How long is a month? How long is a day? How long is an hour? How long is a minute? The answers may surprise you! https://infiniteundo.com/post/25326999628/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-time If you're willing to assume "1 year = 365 days" and so on, then you can just subtract the values of `Date#getTime()` to get the difference in milliseconds, and work your way up from there.

Comment: If you would compare `"2020-25-02 12:00:00"` and `"2020-25-02 13:20:10"` should ethe output be `"1 hour, 20 minutes, 10 seconds"` or should it rather be `"1 hour, 140 minutes, 3610 seconds"`?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use for example `LocalDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Also look into the [`PeriodDuration`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html) class of the ThreeTen Extra project.

Comment: How’s your search engine doing today? Mine relatively easily found for example [Java 8 Difference Between Two Dates](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-in-java/). Only when searching avoid the pages suggesting the poorly designed and outdated date-time classes like `Calendar`, `GregorianCalendar` and `Date`.

Comment: [I downvoted because research must be done to ask a good question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and [why & how to use it](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)

For the difference in years, months and days, there is a `java.time.Period` you can easily use to get what you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2022, 1 , 25 , 12 , 20 , 33);
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

    // get the difference in years, months and days
    Period p = Period.between(now.toLocalDate(), localDateTime.toLocalDate());

    // and print the result(s)
    System.out.println("Difference between " + localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            + " and " + now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) + " is:\n"
            + p.getYears() + " years, " + p.getMonths() + " months, " + p.getDays() + " days");
}
```

The output of this code example would be (depending on the current day, of course):

```
Difference between 2022-01-25T12:20:33 and 2020-02-25T10:52:43.327 is:
1 years, 11 months, 0 days
```

You may use a `java.time.Duration` as shown in one of the other answers in order to get the additional difference in hours, minutes and seconds. See this example (which is basically the one from above plus time calculation):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2022, 1 , 25 , 12 , 20 , 33);
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

    // get the difference in years, months and days (date related difference)
    Period p = Period.between(now.toLocalDate(), localDateTime.toLocalDate());
    // and the difference in hours, minutes and seconds (time-of-day related difference)
    Duration d = Duration.between(now.toLocalTime(), localDateTime.toLocalTime());
    long totalSeconds = d.getSeconds();
    long hours = totalSeconds / 3600;
    long minutes = (totalSeconds % 3600) / 60;
    long seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

    // and print the result(s)
    System.out.println("Difference between " + localDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            + " and " + now.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) + " is:\n"
            + p.getYears() + " years, " + p.getMonths() + " months, " + p.getDays() + " days, "
            + hours + " hours, " + minutes + " minutes, " + seconds + " seconds");
}
```

Output:

```
Difference between 2022-01-25T12:20:33 and 2020-02-25T11:25:42.712 is:
1 years, 11 months, 0 days, 0 hours, 54 minutes, 50 seconds
```

If you are receiving `java.util.Date`s or extending legacy code (or if you are just too lazy to change all your code to using `java.time`), you can make use of the following compatibility methods:

```
LocalDateTime fromDate = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(new Date().toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
Date fromLocalDateTime = Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().toInstant((ZoneOffset.UTC)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 [Date/Time API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro) is flexible in comparing dates.

Example:

```
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate previousDate = LocalDate.of(2000, 7, 1);

Period period = Period.between(previousDate, currentDate);

String output = String.format("%s years , %s months , %s days",
                period.getYears(), period.getMonths(), period.getDays());

System.out.println(output);   
> 19 years , 7 months , 24 days
```

More example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-date-difference).

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html) might help you, if you want to decide between `Period` or `Duration`.

Answer (score 0):

Use java Instant

```java
Instant start, end;
Duration duration = Duration.between(start, stop);
long hours = dur.toHours();
long minutes = dur.toMinutes();
```